# EJS IF statment error with Node JS MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

i am trying to have a server side validation for my App with as

Node js view code

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

var Fullname = req.body.Fullname;
var email = req.body.email;
var rollno = req.body.rollno;
var Birthdate = req.body.Birthdate;
var Gender = req.body.Gender;
var password = req.body.password;
var confirm = req.body.confirm;

  req.checkBody('Fullname', 'Name is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email' , 'Email is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email' , 'Invalid Email').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('rollno', 'Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('Birthdate', 'Date of Birth is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('Gender' , 'Gender is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password' , 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('confirm' , 'Password not Matched').equals(req.body.password);

var errors = req.validationErrors();
if (errors) {
  res.render('/signup' , {
    errors : errors
  });
}
else {
  console.log('No Errors');
}});
```

And EJS is Like

```
<% if(errors){ %>
                <% errors.forEach(function(msg) { %>
                    <div class="alert alert danger"><% msg %></div>
                  <% }); %>
                <% } %>
```

when i try to get /sign up which is get method specified in other route file its output the ejs code in browser with  errors is not defined message???

Comment: What does `errors` returns if there is an real error, and what does it returns if not?

Comment: E:\Project\qec\views\signup.ejs:24 22| <% include partials/title.ejs %> 23| <% include partials/nav.ejs %> >> 24| <% include partials/signupform.ejs %> 25| <% include partials/footer.ejs %> 26| </body> 27| </html> E:\Project\qec\views\partials\signupform.ejs:39 37| <div class="col-lg-12"> 38| <form id="register-form" name="SignupForm" action="/student_home" method="post" role="form" novalidate> >> 39| <% if(errors){ %> 40| <% errors.forEach(function(msg) { %> 41| <div class="alert alert danger"><% msg %></div> 42| <% }); %> errors is not defined

Comment: Yes, but what does the `errors` variable return?

Comment: you mean what can i expect from it?

Comment: it should return alerts over form with all errors of 
 req.checkBody('Fullname', 'Name is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email' , 'Email is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email' , 'Invalid Email').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('rollno', 'Roll Number is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('Birthdate', 'Date of Birth is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('Gender' , 'Gender is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password' , 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('confirm' , 'Password not Matched').equals(req.body.password);

Comment: can we continue our discussion in the chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152283/ejs-if-statment-error-with-node-js-mongodb-45762113

Comment: need 20 reputation i have just 10

Comment: Try `console.log(erroes)` and `console.log(typeof erroes)`

Comment: do you have any social media?

Comment: https://twitter.com/felixfong227